# JFileChooser - regarding the "open" and "cancel" buttons. Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jfilechooser, disambiguation

I am having some trouble using the JFileChooser. Whenever I run the program if I click the "cancel" button right away without selecting a file it will display "hello" and if I click open, it will not do anything. On other hand, if I select a file and click open it will start to display "Hello" (call the createFile method) and will display "hello" if I click "cancel".

My question is how can I find out which button was clicked and to do a specific thing for each like call the die function when clicked cancel and call the createFile function when open is clicked.

I was thinking of something like

```
if(e.getSource() == "Something_I_Dont_know") { do this}
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class Grading{

public static void main(String[] arg){

 new MFrame();

}


}// end of class Grading

class MFrame extends JFrame{

private JCheckBox cum,uc,ucs;
private JButton calc, clear, exit;
private ButtonGroup bg;
private JTextArea display;
private JFileChooser input;

public MFrame(){

    setVisible( true );
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(550,550);

    input = new JFileChooser();
    add( input );
    input.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
                //die();
                createFile();
            }
        }

    );

    setLayout( new FlowLayout() );

    pack();


}// end of constructor

public double gpa(){
 return 1.0;
}// end of gpa method

public void createFile(){
    System.out.println("Hello");
}

public void die(){
    System.exit(0);
}
```

}// end of MFRAME CLASS

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the result of the appropriate `showDialog` method to determine which button was clicked

```
JFileChooser input = new JFileChooser();
int result = input.showSaveDialog(this);
if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    createFile();
} else if (result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
    System.out.println("Cancel was selected");
}
```

Note: Clicking the `X` button on the `JFileChooser` dialog also triggers the `CANCEL_OPTION`.

Read [How to Use File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)

Comment: Thank you! That worked! But out of curiosity, would have I been able to take the ActionListener route? Or was I sort of forced to go the APPROVE_OPTION way?

Comment: Avoid taking that route. While a the cancel is registered with the file chooser's `ActionListener`, the open button does not so will not respond at all. The intent is clearer by using the returned result as shown above.

Answer (score 2):

When initializing components:

```
fileChooser.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        fileChooserActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});
```

The action listener above calls the following method:

```
private void fileChooserActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals(javax.swing.JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION)) {
        System.out.println("approve selection");
    } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals(javax.swing.JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION)) {
        System.out.println("cancel selection");
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: a file/folder must be selected for the approve selection to work

Comment: This seems to be the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

In most situations it is sufficient to check for the approve option:

```
JFileChooser input = new JFileChooser();
if (input.showSaveDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    createFile();
}
```

If anything else than approve was clicked, you just do not create the file.
This works for

- showOpenDialog()
- showSaveDialog()
- pretty much any cases of JOptionPane usage

There is some exception when you need to check more. Imagine the user quits the application and it pops up a warning that the document is still not saved:

Unsaved data! Do you want to save? (Yes/No/Cancel)

In this case you need to check as you have three different outcomes:

- yes: Save the data and exit
- no: Just exit
- cancel: do not exit